# Offsetting a tiled shape inside the image frame

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, offset

I have an image that only contains a tiled shape in it with everywhere else black. However, this tiled pattern can be shifted/offset anywhere in the image particularly over the image borders. Knowing that this shape can be fit inside the image after offsetting it and leaving the borders black, how can I calculate how many pixels in x and y coordinates it needs to get offset for that to happen in an optimized way?

Input image
[image]

Desired output after offset/shiftimg
[image]

My thought was getting connected components in the image, check which labels are on the border, calculate the longest distance between each axis shapes that are on the border and offsetting in  the axis' with those values. It can work but I feel like there should be smarter ways.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question. Post the image you want to tile over these pictures and show an output example.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by offsetting it? could you provide a code snippet that shows applying an offset to your original image?

Comment: @Ehsan by offsetting, i mean shifting or wrapping the image like offset filter in Photoshop. The input image is the first image. If you offset that image, you will get all the contents inside the image frame such as the second photo shown as a desired output. I’m just looking for a way to offset the image enough pixels so those shapes fall inside the frame and not be on the borders. Does it make sense?

Comment: @fmw42 look my comment above please

Comment: @Yasin I understood the question and the concept. What I am not sure about is how you have your original image data and how you apply the offset. I do not know anything about photoshop. Would be helpful if you provide in code sense what you mean by offset.

Comment: You can sequence through the columns of your input image and count the number of white pixels in each column. Find the gap of fully black columns and its center column. Then shift the image by that amount. In python opencv, crop the image into two parts using numpy slicing or some similar method. Then swap the two and put them back together using numpy hstack. You can count the white pixels in a column using np.count_nonzero().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the details of what I put in my comment for doing that with Python/OpenCV/Numpy. Is this what you want?

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold to binary
- Count the number of white pixels in each column and store in array
- Find the first and last black (zero count) element in the array
- Get the center x values
- Crop the image into left and right parts at the center x
- Stack them together horizontally in the opposite order
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('black_white.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# count number of white pixels in columns as new array
count = np.count_nonzero(thresh, axis=0)

# get first and last x coordinate where black (count==0)
first_black = np.where(count==0)[0][0]
last_black = np.where(count==0)[0][-1]

# compute x center
black_center = (first_black + last_black) // 2
print(black_center)

# crop into two parts
left = img[0:hh, 0:black_center]
right = img[0:hh, black_center:ww]

# combine them horizontally after swapping
result = np.hstack([right, left])

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("black_white_rolled.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It’s almost what i’m looking for, however the result must go within the image borders. In your output, they are crossing the top and bottom, unless the same procedure has to be done vertically?

Comment: Yes, the same procedure needs to be done on my result in the vertical dimension if you want the vertical black region split and swapped. I will leave that to you. If you have trouble, get back and I will try to help.

Comment: Perfect! it's almost same idea but wasn't sure how to efficiently execute it. This is a neat implementation. Thanks :)

Comment: Same idea as what?  Did you fill out my example for the vertical part? If so, post the full solution.

Comment: Same idea as the one I had posted in the original question. The last paragraph. Your implementation is efficient and what I was looking for.